# How do i fix a permission denied error on my mac?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Getting permission denied when trying to run python code using visual studio code editor using MAC OS Mojave 10.14.5.

I ran the same code in spider IDE and runs great.  Tried to log in as su but same result

```
(base) user-MBP:~ user$ 
/Users/user/Documents/readingUsingPandas.py
bash: /Users/user/Documents/readingUsingPandas.py: Permission denied
(base) user-MBP:~ user$
```

Comment: Is the bash argument running a bash file? If so the bash file needs to be executable.

Comment: Running python file

Comment: Python scripts also need to be executable. Try `chmod +x /Users/user/Documents/readingUsingPandas.py`

Comment: Yes using chmod +x in the cmd line worked.